# synchronous multiple promises inside if statement

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

My function ends before finalizing the promises within the if.
The idea is to be able to execute the promises (that are necessary) in a synchronous way for when the object is returned, it is complete and all the promises have finished.

```
let var1 = '';
let var2 = '';
let var3 = '';

if(condition1){
  promise1().then(result =>{
    var1 = result;
  )
}

if(condition2){
  promise2().then(result =>{
    var2 = result;
  )
}

if(condition3){
  promise2().then(result =>{
    var3 = result;
  )
}

let object = {
  var1: var1,
  var2: var2,
  var3: var3
}

resolve(object);
```

What I did initially was to use `Promise.all`, but it did not work, and the function returns the object without finishing the promises. This was my implementation.

```
let var1 = '';
let var2 = '';
let var3 = '';
let array_promises = [];
if(condition1){
  promise1().then(result =>{
    var1 = result;
    array_promises.push(result);
  )
}

if(condition2){
  promise2().then(result =>{
    var2 = result;
    array_promises.push(result);
  )
}

if(condition3){
  promise2().then(result =>{
    var3 = result;
    array_promises.push(result);
  )
}
.
.
.


Promise.all(array_promises).then(()=>{
  let object = {
   var1: var1,
   var2: var2,
   var3: var3
   .
   .
   .
  }
  resolve(object);
});
```

It did not work either. returns object without completing the execution of the promises.
I do not want to use any third-party npm or anything like that. Any guide or suggestion?, I may be doing something wrong

Comment: There are a a few syntax errors, you might want to fix those?

Comment: UPDATED. yeah, I had a problem with the if syntax.

Comment: do you mean in a serial way, or in series? Promises are not synchronous and can not be synchronous because they are by nature asynchronous

Comment: FYI, assigning values to a higher scope from an asynchronous callback like you are doing when you  do `var1 = result` and then attempting to use `var1` outside of the asynchronous callback is almost always wrong in Javascript.  That is usually a warning sign that you are doing things wrong.

Comment: Also, showing us real code that actually does some real asynchronous operation will generally get you a lot more helpful answer than just making up some do-nothing code.  In many cases, when you show us the real code, we can show you even better ways to code it than you will likely figure out from our theoretical answers to your pseudo-code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `Promise.all` on an *array of Promises* - if the array doesn't contain actual Promises, then the `Promise.all` won't wait for anything, and will resolve as soon as it can. Your `array_promises` isn't an array of `Promise`s, it's just an array of values that might get pushed to. Try calling `Promise.all` on the *promises themselves* instead:

```js
const condition1 = true;
const condition2 = false;
const condition3 = true;
const promise1 = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200, 'p1'));
const promise2 = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200, 'p2'));
const promise3 = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200, 'p3'));

Promise.all(([
  condition1 ? promise1() : '',
  condition2 ? promise2() : '',
  condition3 ? promise3() : '',
])).then(([var1, var2, var3]) => {
  const returnObj = {
    var1,
    var2,
    var3,
  };
  console.log(returnObj);
})
```

This works because, in the array passed to `Promise.all`, any values that are not promises will simply be passed as-is to the `.then`.

By your `resolve(object);`, it *looks* as if this whole code is inside a `Promise` constructor. If that's the case, it would probably be better if you instead *returned* the `Promise.all` call, instead of explicitly creating another new Promise.

Comment: super accurate and clean response. Thank you.